# How does one install a gem that a chef library (not a recipe) requires?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a cookbook `foo` that provides functionality as a library (and has no recipes). This functionality requires `rest-client` (which used to be built-in to earlier Chef versions, but was removed). The obvious answer is to add a `gem 'rest-client'` to the cookbook metadata, but this breaks `berks vendor` because `rest-client` is not installed and it seemingly cannot install it, either. The other obvious answer is to add a `chef_gem` incantation immediately before `require 'rest-client'`, but since it's a library and not a recipe `chef_gem` isn't callable. How can I ensure that `foo` gets `rest-client` installed before its library is compiled without putting it in the cookbook metadata?